Gridlayout breaks when test a lower inc screen
Gridlayout breaks when I test a lower inc screen, I am developing an application for my project but I couldn't find a way to fix it.
I want the UI to stay the same when I lower the inches, but I couldn't succeed. its complately breaks when I lower the inch.
Can you help me on how to fix it?


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_view"

        />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="361dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_view"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="307dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/yayin"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_live"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/yayın"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/baskan"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_person"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/baskan"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_contact"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/iletisim"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/eczane"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_phar"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/eczane"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/belediye"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_homebel"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/bel"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/vefat"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_cemet"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/vefat"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/alo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_153"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/alo"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="383dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/top_view"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/test"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>

I want the UI to remain the same depending on whether the screen inch grows or shrinks.
